# Performing a sum with Swift

Tags: comparative-review, swift, closure

I wrote the following in Swift to perform a sum:

```
let total:Double = session.courses.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.totalPrice() }
```

It's concise, it does the job but it does not seems very readable to me. Wouldn't a "classic" `for` loop be more explicit/readable/maintainable?

```
var total:Double = 0
for dish in session.courses {
    total += dish.totalPrice()
}
```

Should closures always be the way to go in Swift?

Answer (score 2):

Both solutions are correct. Some advantages of the "functional" approach
with `reduce()`:

- Concise code.
- Returns a *constant.* It is clear to the reader that
  `total` is assigned to exactly once, and the compiler may use this
  information for optimizing code.
- The type annotation on the result value is not needed:

  ```
  let total = session.courses.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.totalPrice() }
  ```

  because that can be inferred from the compiler automatically.
  This will continue to compile without changes if the type of
  `totalPrice()` is changed, e.g. from `Double` to `Float`.

To increase legibility, you can use named closure parameters instead
of the `$n` shortcuts:

```
let total = session.courses.reduce(0) { (partialSum, dish) in
    partialSum + dish.totalPrice()
}
```

Comment: +1 for legibility! I find the `$n` shortcuts incredibly hard to read, and they offer no information on what the values represent.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternatives:

`let sum = session.courses.map({$0.totalPrice()}).reduce(0, +)`

Another note, I think it's more elegant to implement `totalPrice` as computed variable instead of function.

Another way is to use `forEach` :

```
var sum = 0
session.courses.forEach {sum+=$0.totalPrice()}
```

as @Martin R mentioned the functional approach has some advantages especially that the result is constant.